# python - 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, mongodb

Very new to python and trying to query a mongo db.

I am following this tutorial(https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask) and I have mongodb installed with some sample restaurant data.

```
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    cursor = db.find({"borough": "Bronx"})

    result = []

    for restaurant in cursor:
        result.append(restaurant)

    return result
```

Edit **

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ciprian/dev/todo-api/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ciprian/dev/todo-api/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/ciprian/dev/todo-api/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ciprian/dev/todo-api/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ciprian/dev/todo-api/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/ciprian/dev/todo-api/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/home/ciprian/dev/todo-api/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1740, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/home/ciprian/dev/todo-api/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 885, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/home/ciprian/dev/todo-api/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 57, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "/home/ciprian/dev/todo-api/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Solution which seems to work for me:

```
from bson.json_util import dumps

@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    cursor = db.find({"borough": "Bronx"})

    result = []

    for restaurant in cursor:
        result.append(restaurant)

    return dumps(result)
```

Comment: post the complete stacktrace

Comment: I hope that's what you mean.

Comment: Why not just do `return cursor` because `result` would be just a copy of `cursor`

Comment: @Ciprian, you should probably edit the title of your question so it's a bit more specific.

Comment: @DominicBett TypeError: 'Cursor' object is not callable

Comment: @Ciprian try converting `cursor` to a list i.e `list(cursor)`

Comment: same error. `ret = list(cursor) return ret`

Comment: @Ciprian, were you unable to fix the error and get your code working ?

Comment: no. I will keep trying. maybe read a little more about this online.

Comment: @downshift I managed to get it to work.

Comment: Great to hear you got it working, cheers